# Rails 3.1 / Ruby - Nested loops?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some trouble with nested loops. Does anyone know a better way of doing this:

```
@product.tracks.each do |t|
    t.artists_tracks.each do |at|
        at.role = at.artist.role
        at.position = at.artist.position
        at.save
    end
end
```

I'm getting an *undefined method role =* error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Loop looks good to me. What attributes to you have on each models?

Answer (score 1):

```
@product.tracks.each do |track|
    track.artists_tracks.each do |at|
        at.role = track.artist.role
        at.position = track.artist.position
        at.save
    end
end
```

But yeah.. sure thing you need to review your models attrs

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- You should be able to write `@product.artist_tracks` provided you have a `has_many :artist_tracks, :through => :artists`.
- `at.role = at.artist.role`. You are breaking the basic SQL rule of not having data duplicated, let the `artist` have the role.